# Выложить на бесплатный хостинг tcp сервер на Python. (НЕ WEB !!!)

Tags: сервер, хостинг, tcp

Сервер получает получает строку, проверяет есть ли она в базе данных и возвращает ответ.

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from database import DataBase

def main():
    DataBase.connect_to_db('keys.db')

    host, port = '', 789

    tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_socket.bind((host, port))
    tcp_socket.listen()

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = tcp_socket.accept()

        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        data = data.strip()

        resp_text = 'key exist' if DataBase.is_key_exist(data) else 'key not exist'

        client_socket.send(resp_text.encode('utf-8'))
        client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Мне нужна статья с инструкцией как залить это на бесплатный хостинг.
Сколько не гуглил, постоянно вылезают статьи как заливать web приложения, а мне нужно tcp сервер. Долго пыхтел с https://www.pythonanywhere.com, но там походу только web.

Посоветуйте подходящий бесплатный хостинг и САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ ИНСТРУКЦИЮ - как залить сервер (особенно интересует какой порт указывать).

Comment: web-приложения работают на веб-серверах, а веб-сервера используют tcp